# How can you call using jquery with custom route in asp.net mvc controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

if I have this as a action to my controller

```
[route('admin/edit/{name}')]
public ActionResult GetName(string name)
{
}
```

how can I call this using jquery?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
 document.location = '@Url.Action("GetName","MyController")'+'?'+'name = @value';
```

link will be like

```
MyController/GetName?name=value
```

or something like this:

```
document.location = '/MyController/GetName?name='+value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you specified jQuery:

1. Assuming you've got config done for [attribute routing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx#enabling-attribute-routing)
2. Unsure if you meant the `name` parameter to be optional, and if so:

   - `[Route('admin/edit/{name?})]`
   - `/admin/edit` and `/admin/edit/HelloWorld`

You can use [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) to GET the page.

```
$.get("admin/edit/HelloWorld", //HelloWorld is the {name?} parameter
       function(data) { //do something with response if needed
       console.log(data); 
 });
```